# Conflicting types error when trying to build - types are the same

Tags: c, linux, eclipse-cdt

Error when trying to compile. Its the basic code and everything looks fine. Tried to rebuild, freshen, update, re-resolve and nothing helps.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type conflicting types for
> ‘skirt’   domains.c   /domains    line 21 C/C++ Problem

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef long long int64;

int main()
{
    struct timespec iter_start, iter_end;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &iter_start); // iteracijai pirmai
    printf("hello");
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &iter_end);

    int64 duration = skirt(iter_end, iter_start);

    return(0);
}

int64 skirt(const struct timespec after, const struct timespec before)
{
    return ((int64)after.tv_sec - (int64)before.tv_sec) * (int64)1000000
         + ((int64)after.tv_nsec - (int64)before.tv_nsec) / 1000;
}
```

Comment: You have to declare the function before using it.

Comment: Either add a prototype for the function at the beginning, or move the definition of `skirt()` before `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the function before using it. Worked like a charm.